# MVC5 View: Set up and get an index while looping through the model

Tags: c#, view, indexing, asp.net-mvc-5, pagedlist

In my view I am trying to set up an index so I can mark each row of the table as even or odd. I did a lot of searching and found a solution but the solution I found was for when the model was IEnumerable but mine is PagedList.IPagedList.

[Link to the other solution I found](http://benmccallum.wordpress.com/2011/04/28/a-foreach-loop-with-an-index-thanks-to-linq/)

```
@foreach (var item in Model.Select((x, i) => new { Data = x, Index = i }))
{
   <tr @if ((item.index) % 2 == 0){ <text> class=”even” </text> } else {<text> class=”odd” </text>}>

         <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.thing)</td>
         <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.thing2)</td>
         <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.thing3)</td>
   </tr>
}
```

I get this error in the edditor:

cannot use a lambda expression as an argument to a dynamically dispatched operation without first casting it to a delegate or expression tree type.

and this error if I run it:

'AnonymousType#1' does not contain a definition for 'index' and no extension method 'index' accepting a first argument of type 'AnonymousType#1' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Any ideas? or can I just not do this with a PagedList.IPagedList model?

EDIT:
Fixed one thing Renamed the "Index" in the for each to "index" Still getting the same, in editor error. and the running error is saying that all these:

@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.thing)

need to be changed too

@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.data.thing)

After doing this it runs but I am not getting class="even or class "odd" in the  tag.

Is there maybe an easier overall way of doing this?

Comment: well your anonymous type property is `Index` and you're looking for `index`.  I'd start by fixing that

Comment: You are setting a property called `Index` on your anonymous type and trying to access it using `index`.

Comment: Fixed the Index index thing. Now it looks like I have to change <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.thing)</td> to this <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.data.thing)</td> Is there an easier way to get an index in this situation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you spelled `item.index` without capital `I`. That explains the error you see.

That said, you should really be using for instead of foreach, and not only because you need an index. Expressions as `DisplayFor(modelItem => item.thing)` in MVC assume that right hand side of lambda depends on left hand side, and you may run into issue if this is not the case.

Because of all this, I think you need a for loop. Luckily IPagedList implements `IList<T>`, so this is not a big deal:

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count(); i++)
{
   <tr @if (i % 2 == 0){ <text> class=”even” </text> } else {<text> class=”odd” </text>}>

         <td>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model[i].thing)</td>
         <td>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model[i].thing2)</td>
         <td>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model[i].thing3)</td>
   </tr>
}
```